# Can a background video element be loaded last?

Tags: html, video

I have a Webflow exported site (www.puzzlefactory.uk). It has a background video. I would like that background video to load AFTER the rest of the site has loaded. I have no idea how to do this.

The closest I could find was this answer:
[Load the video element last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265861/load-the-video-element-last) by @Offbeatmammal

I wanted to ask the answerer if this could be made to apply to background video, but am afraid of being banned from StackOverflow. (Despite the clear relevance/link)

This is the existing code:

```
<div data-poster-url="videos/bgvideo2-poster-00001.jpg" data-video-urls="videos/bgvideo2-transcode.mp4,videos/bgvideo2-transcode.webm" data-autoplay="true" data-loop="true" data-wf-ignore="true" class="background-video lazyload w-background-video w-background-video-atom">
<video autoplay="" loop="" style="background-image:url(&quot;videos/bgvideo2-poster-00001.jpg&quot;)" muted="" playsinline="" data-wf-ignore="true">
<source src="videos/bgvideo2-transcode.mp4" data-wf-ignore="true">
<source src="videos/bgvideo2-transcode.webm" data-wf-ignore="true"></video></div>
```

I have tried LazySizes (lazyload plugin), but it caused an error where both desktop and mobile videos displayed on all browsers/devices. (They are the same set of code linking to video files with different aspect ratios for desktop and mobile devices.)

I would like the background video to load AFTER the rest of the site has loaded.

Comment: background video is just a `<video>` element like any other, so yes the same sorts of rules apply ... apply the video source after the DOM is ready